# What is the best jquery tooltip plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What is the best jquery tooltip plugin?

Answer (score 9):

check out qtip.  its my go to tool tip plugin, very flexible and easy

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

This is the updated version of the library: [qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/)

Answer (score 2):

A good and complex example of qtip is
[Talking Pictures](http://apps.facebook.com/talking_pictures/), Which is a facebook application.